# YUICompressor path issue

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, yui-compressor

I'm trying to minify some css automatically in WebStorm.  I'm using YUICompressor.  Here is my file watcher:

[image]

Here is the command it is outputting:

> D:\projects\projectname>"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm
> 2017.1.1\jre64/bin/java" -jar D:/projects/projectname/node_modules/yuicompressor/build/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar
> "D:\projects\projectname\css\materialize.css" -o
> "D:\projects\projectname\css\materialize.min.cs s"

And here is the error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> projectsprojectnamecssmaterialize.min.css:\projects\projectname\css\materialize.css
> (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For now I just used the `Create output file from stdout` option.  It looks like this:

[image]

This results in the expected output, but I will leave this unanswered for now in case someone can explain why the path parameters are having the slashes stripped out.